# Connect local postgres database to Google Cloud

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, google-cloud-platform, cloud

I'm pretty much new to cloud services (and tbh, backend is not my area of expertise) and I'm trying to deploy my local database to google cloud so I can show my app in a portfolio.

The google cloud shell required me to log with my postgres user and password, and I think I got it right because it showed the following in the console, but there's no clue about my local databases

```
You are now connected to database "postgres" as user "postgres".
postgres-> [\l
                                                List of databases
     Name      |       Owner       | Encoding |  Collate   |   Ctype    |            Access privileges
---------------+-------------------+----------+------------+------------+-----------------------------------------
 cloudsqladmin | cloudsqladmin     | UTF8     | en_US.UTF8 | en_US.UTF8 |
 postgres      | cloudsqlsuperuser | UTF8     | en_US.UTF8 | en_US.UTF8 |
 template0     | cloudsqladmin     | UTF8     | en_US.UTF8 | en_US.UTF8 | =c/cloudsqladmin                       +
               |                   |          |            |            | cloudsqladmin=CTc/cloudsqladmin
 template1     | cloudsqlsuperuser | UTF8     | en_US.UTF8 | en_US.UTF8 | =c/cloudsqlsuperuser                   +
               |                   |          |            |            | cloudsqlsuperuser=CTc/cloudsqlsuperuser
(4 rows)

postgres->
```

Also, I'm open to other options if anyone has a better/easier choice to upload a db (unless said option is heroku, because I couldn't make it work)

Comment: What do you want to do? What do you expect? Can you detail these points?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I already solved it but if anyone happens to have a similar problem I did the following: first I created a sql backup of my local db. Then I had to create a bucket and upload said sql backup there. Finally, on the instance tab, you have to go to import and select the bucket, and chose where you want to import the backup.

Answer (score 0):

You have to migrate your on-premises PostgreSQL to GCP.

This documentation will help
https://cloud.google.com/solutions/migrating-postgresql-to-gcp